# Have Feeling Of Sex During Fasting

Tags: sawm

Assalamu Alaikum,

Am 20 aged women, and I got recently married, I have a question which is related Ramadan.

While fasting, me and spouse kiss each other and hug each other, we had such a sexual feeling, but we didn’t fall to sexual intercourse,

Let me know it will break my fast..? What should I want to do further, Want to fast again..? Please help me with a correct answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
                                  بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

In regard to your question that asked:

> While fasting, me and spouse kiss each other and hug each other, we
>   had such a sexual feeling, but we didn’t fall to sexual intercourse,
>   Let me know it will break my fast..?

The answer is : No, doing such acts as you mentioned, do not invalidate your fasting in case that you are not Jonob. Actually it won’t be invalid if semen has not come out of your body. / For more info. you'd better refer to the reference. (Of course if you are familiar woth Farsi or Urdu).

**Reference:**

http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa9658 (in Farsi)

http://www.islamquest.net/ur/archive/question/fa9658 (in Urdu)

Answer (score 1):

The important thing taqwa of Allah. If you can control your desires and know your limits when you and your spouse get intimate, then you are allowed to get intimate.

Prophet Muhammed (صلى الله عليه وسلم) would kiss and embrace (his wives) while fasting and he had most control of his desires.

> Let me know it will break my fast..? what should i wanna do further,
>   Wanna fast again..? Please help me with a correct answer..

**No,** kissing and embracing will not break your fast.

There are numerous Hadith references, I'd suggest you to search yourself a few more on sunnah.com

**Hadith References**

```
http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/13/90
http://www.sunnah.com/urn/406490
http://www.sunnah.com/urn/2059140
http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/8/46
```